# How to grant access permision for multiple database and multiple tables to a user in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

I have two databases WORLD,TEST each one contain 3 Tables.I also created a new User test_grant now i want to give SELECT,DELETE,UPDATE permission to test_grant user.But here i want to give two tables permission of TEST database rather than all tables permission in single SQL statement.

Comment: challenge is to grant the permissions in a single statement or grant permission only for particular tables in a database?

Comment: Chalenges is to grant permission only for particular table not all the tables

Answer (score 3):

```
GRANT ... ON dbname.tablename TO user@... IDENTIFIED BY ...;
```

You can grant `ON *.*`, `ON dbname.*`, `ON db.tbl`, or even on column(s).

You will need multiple GRANTs for multiple tables.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK you can't add a grant like this in a single statement.

If you read the documentation it doesn't make it clear but you can only have one object in the *priv_level* position:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/grant.html